# how can I get values from dictionary which has contain entry values for form app

Tags: python, dictionary

```
def myclick():
   print(d["string0"])

d = {}

for i in range(0, 32):

    d["string{0}".format(i)] = Entry(window, width=5)
    d["string{0}".format(i)].place(x=out_x_pos, y=out_y_pos + distbetweenrows * i)

    d["string{0}{0}".format(i)] = Entry(window, width=5)
    d["string{0}{0}".format(i)].place(x=out_x_pos + col_distance, y=out_y_pos + distbetweenrows * i)
buton= Button(window, text="tikla", command=myclick)
buton.place(x=500, y=50)

window.mainloop()
```

There are 64 number of entry values I need to get from user. Entry boxes are existing but when I write a number inside it and click the button, it always shows me the first value of it like `.!entry`.

Can you help me fix it?
Thanks for your answers.

Answer (score 1):

In this line: `d["string{0}".format(i)] = Entry(window, width=5)` you set the value of `d["string0"]` to an `Entry` object. So if you just do `print(d["string0"])` you will print the Entry object instead of what's written inside it so you should change your `myclick` function to:

```
def myclick():
    print(d["string0"].get())
```

Now you will first get the content of your `Entry` object and then print this.

I hope this helps.

Also, it's more readable to use the same formatting for all your variables, since you use `out_x_pos`, `out_y_pos`and `col_distance`, it would be more logical to also use `dist_between_rows` and `my_click()`. This is also the [pythonic](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#id45) way of writing variables.